# AngularJS multiple routes using JSON data ids

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

We are new to [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) and finding one-or-two problems with setting up multiple routes when using ID's from Json Data.

We are trying to replicate [AngularJS Tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07), so we can click each 'View' button to display a more detailed page of the selected 'Warranty Item' same as the tutorial.

We have uploaded our AngularJS problem to [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vv3onQFnqmVRTuDJ8Xtu?p=preview), If anyone can see something we're missing or know a better route to go down please let us know.

**App.js State with ResultSet.JobID**

```
.state('home.singleWarranty', {
    url: '/singlewarranty/{resultset.JobID}',
    templateUrl: 'singlewarranty.html',
    controller: 'warrantyListController'
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [a working/updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jEXPuiI6wRArBzOjIIx3?p=preview)

Because there are these states

```
  .state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'homeController'
  })
 .state('home.singleWarranty', {
    url: '/singleWarranty/:jobID',
    templateUrl: 'singlewarranty.html',
    controller: 'warrantyListController'
  })
```

We need to build the url like this

```
<a href="#/home/singleWarranty/{{resultset.JobID}}">View</a>
```

Instead of this original

```
// <a href="#/warranty/{{resultset.JobID}}">View</a>
```

The point is that state `'home.singleWarranty'` inherits/extends the url from its parent. So we have to include the parents '/home' as well.

*Other solution:*

In case we would like to start the url in a child state from the begining, we can do it like this

```
 .state('home.singleWarranty', {
    url: '^/singleWarranty/:jobID',
```

See the **`^`** at the url begining. Then even this would work:

```
<a href="#/singleWarranty/{{resultset.JobID}}">View</a>
```

Check the updated plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jEXPuiI6wRArBzOjIIx3?p=preview)

Comment: Great to see that! Enjoy amazing `UI-Router` ;)